# Jquery changing image width in the horizontal carousel

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the image carousel to one of the images to have 500px width and the rest 100px width, example can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Uu3aP/3/

Only the image that locates in the middle of the div, sliding or not, should have 500px. the image should change as it is centred in the middle of the div. For example,if you give id 1/7 to the list, the one in middle changes size, if it is id 1 or the other ones

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var EASING = 0.05,
    FPS = 60,
    $paneTarget = $('#scroll'),
    $paneContainer = $('#scrollContainer'),
    windowWidth = $(window).width(),
    containerWidth = 0,
    maxScroll = 0,
    posX = 0,   // Keep track of the container position with posX
    targetX = 0,
    animInterval = false;   // No interval is set by default

$paneTarget.find('li').each(function() {
    containerWidth += $(this).width();
    $paneContainer.width(containerWidth);
});

// Set maximum amount the container can scroll
// negative because we're gonna scroll to left
maxScroll = -(containerWidth - windowWidth);

// This gets called from the setInterval and handles the animating of the scroll container
function animationLoop() {
    var dx = targetX - posX,    // Difference
        vx = dx * EASING;       // Velocity

    // Add velocity to x position and update css with new position
    posX += vx;
    $paneContainer.css({left: posX});

    // When end target is reached stop the interval
    if (Math.round(posX) === targetX) {
        clearInterval(animInterval);
        animInterval = false;
    }
}

$paneTarget.on('mousemove', function(event) {
    // Calculate the new x position for the scroll container
    targetX = Math.round((event.pageX / windowWidth) * maxScroll);

    // Only start animation interval when it's not already running
    if (!animInterval) {
        animInterval = setInterval(animationLoop, 1000 / FPS);
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Addclass to one of your `<li>` node and change width for this class.

**Additional HTML**

```
<li class="special"><img  src="http://www.luxuryselfcatering.uk.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/placeholder-1-500x350.jpg" alt="" /></li>
```

**Additional CSS**

```
#scrollContainer li.special {
    width: 500px;
}
```

Here is http://jsfiddle.net/Uu3aP/14/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Piotr Karasiński, but this is not what I need, the image should change as it is centred in the middle of the div. For example, if the if you give id 1/7 to the list, the one in middle changes size, if it is id 1 or the other ones